# NPM for node.js(user),how to install core dependencies without trying to find each one

Tags: node.js, npm, javascript

I am just a user with no programming skills,but have learned how to use packages,however a lot of packages cannot install because of missing this,requires that etc,

Question:is their a node package for downloading core packages for node.js?

Example gyp is a common error for missing packages,their are a lot of gyp packages,something to download all of gyp,and other core dependencies

thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not sure you've given enough info here. `gyp` is used to compile things, so perhaps you are downloading modules that cannot be compiled on your system? Your question seems like it asks how to not install certain things, but that seems weird since if some sub-dependency doesn't get installed, chances are nothing will work. Also, what do you mean by "downloading core packages"?

Comment: hi sorry for the bad grammer, example,I am on windows,if I was freshly after downloading NPM with no packages installed,is there a package I can download to automatically install important packages,that a lot of other packages depend on,every second package I just get error messages about missing modules/packages EVEN packages that do not require any dependencies

Comment: Found the answer on the related section,I didnt know I had to install python to use a lot of the node packages,thanks for your help